# D3.js - Stacked Barchart from JSON?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to recreate this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1c5eqrp3/3/

In the context of a horizontal stacked bar chart that I am building using my data.

```js
var bar1Data = [{
    position: 1,
    label: '70k',
    value: 1708026
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 1915059
  },
];

//sort bars based on value
bar1Data = bar1Data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.position, b.position);
})

var colors = ['green', 'blue'];

var bars = d3.select('#bars')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 800)
  .attr('height', 200);

bars.selectAll('rect')
  .data(bar1Data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return sum(bar1Data.value, 0, i);
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  })
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('height', 100);

function sum(array, start, end) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) total += array[i];
  return total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

All was going well, until I tried to get it to read the bar1Data I created.

Now, I am getting the following errors:

```
Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "[object Object]".
(anonymous) @ d3.js:1211
selection_each @ d3.js:1176
selection_attr @ d3.js:1233
(anonymous) @ bars3.js:23
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ bars3.js:1
bars3.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at sum (bars3.js:33)
    at SVGRectElement.<anonymous> (bars3.js:26)
    at SVGRectElement.<anonymous> (d3.js:1209)
    at Selection.selection_each [as each] (d3.js:1176)
    at Selection.selection_attr [as attr] (d3.js:1233)
    at bars3.js:25
```

I have been greatly struggling to create a stacked horizontal bar chart using d3.v5. I have been trying various examples using d3.v4 but I have not been able to get them to work. This was the simplest, most light-weight example I have found. But it does not yet include scales (which I shall hopefully put in a little later).

Could you please help me to solve this issue with an explanation?

Comment: what is data of  `HHPro.json`? It seems like revalue `bar1Data ` error

Comment: Hey, that's just the data I'm calling from. Instead of putting that in here I just changed the values in the array to match that of the JSON. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `.attr('width', function(d){ return d;})`, you're setting the width of the bar to the entire object `d`. You need to understand that `.data(bar1Data)` creates one entry per value of `bar1Data`, and that that value is accessible as `d` in all those functions. That means that, as soon as you've passed `.data(bar1Data)`, you shouldn't directly touch that object anymore.

Now, from your data I seem to understand that you want to use the values of all preceding entries to calculate the cumulative sum up to that point. I will implement that in the answer, but would also like to point you towards `stack = d3.stack()`, which does it for you.

Note also that your values are too large. You need to transform them using a domain, otherwise you get one pixel per dollar (or other unit of money), which means the bars are drawn 100x the width of your monitor to the right.

```js
var bar1Data = [{
    position: 1,
    label: '70k',
    value: 50
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 40
  },
];

//sort bars based on value
bar1Data = bar1Data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.position, b.position);
})

var colors = ['green', 'blue'];

var bars = d3.select('#bars')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 800)
  .attr('height', 200);

bars.selectAll('rect')
  .data(bar1Data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    // Note that I use `.map` here to take only the `.value` attribute
    // from the data and create an array of numbers.
    return sum(bar1Data.map((e) => e.value), 0, i);
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  })
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('height', 100);

function sum(array, start, end) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) total += array[i];
  return total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='bars'>
</div>
```